# Reinstalling package if specific file is missing

Tags: puppet

I need to reinstall a package with Puppet if a specific file is missing. How can I achive this? In never versions of Puppet is a the `onlyif` parameter available but we still use Puppet 3.1.

Comment: What type do you think has an `onlyif` parameter in newer Puppet that did not have it in Puppet 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

Do not mistake Puppet for some kind of baroque script engine.  Reinstalling a package is an *action*, whereas Puppet classes, resources, and DSL in general focus on describing *state*.  Puppet's general paradigm is that you tell it what state you want, and it figures out for itself what actions, if any, to take to achieve that state.  Even `Exec` resources are best conceptualized and used as representations of state to be managed.

Puppet `Package` resources do not recognize a state of "installed but broken", or any similar thing, and therefore they have no sense of a need to reinstall (as opposed to updating) a package, nor any mechanism for doing so.

If your concern is with only one specific file that you expect the package to provide, then you should consider putting that file under direct management (via a `File` resource) instead of relying on a package reinstallation to recover it if it should go missing.

However, you should consider what flaw in your system's configuration or security policy affords any plausible likelihood that random system files will unexpectedly go missing.  You should especially do this if you are using the file in question as a canary to detect broader damage.

Nevertheless, if you remain firm about doing what you ask, then an `Exec` resource can help.  The details of what you would need are unclear, but you can take this as a pattern:

```
exec { 'Ensure package mypackage good':
  command => '/usr/bin/yum -y reinstall mypackage',
  creates => '/path/to/some_file',
  require => Package['mypackage']
}
```

The `Exec` type also has `unless` and `onlyif` parameters (including in Puppet 3.1), but the `creates` parameter serves the specific case of using the presence or absence of a file to determine whether the command needs to be run, which is exactly what you want.

Note also the `require` parameter.  This presumes that package 'mypackage' is under Puppet management (not shown), and guarantees that the `Exec` will not be synced before the package.  That way, if the package is altogether absent, you can be sure that Puppet will install it (supposing that's what you have specified) before testing the presence of any file it is expected to provide.